# Cache a result set for a class method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, rspec

I have a pretty db-intensive class method in one of my models:

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord
  def self.collection_tree
    pages = []
    walk_tree do |page, level|
      pages << page
    end
    pages
  end
end
```

I'd like to cache the result so only the first call to the method invokes the DB queries.

I tried it like this:

```
def self.collection_tree
  return @collection_tree if @collection_tree

  @collection_tree = []
  walk_tree do |page, level|
    @collection_tree << page
  end
  @collection_tree
end
```

But this resulted in specs failing randomly - it seems that this isn't reset between specs they way as I expected.

Is there another way to cache something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the cache directly with [fetch method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store/fetch)

```
def self.collection_tree
  Rails.cache.fetch('collection_tree') do    
    collection_tree = []
    walk_tree do |page, level|
      collection_tree << page
    end
    collection_tree
  end
end
```